# Set html datepicker to null

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form on a php page that submits information about events. Information submitted is stored in a MySQL database.

When a user does not select a date from the date picker, 0000-00-00 is inserted into the database. The column is set to default to null, leading me to think that this behavior is caused by the datepicker.

Can anyone suggest a way to allow insertion of a null value?

NOTE - I'm using the default html datepicker, not the jqueryUI version.

EDIT - on closer inspection its because the datatype in the database is a date, nothing to do with the datepicker.

**form**

```
<form action="add_event.php" method="post">

    <div class="textWrap">
        <label for="dateEndInput" id="title3">End Date</label>
        <input id="dateEndInput" name="dateEndInput" type="text" value="" tabindex="3">
    </div>

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having an additional PHP statement before you do your SQL transaction that checks specifically for that value and var type and then setting it to null if it matches those conditions?

```
if ($date && $date === '0000-00-00') {
    $date = null;
}
```

Alternatively, there's an inbuilt date_parse function

```
$date = '0000-00-00';
$parse_date = date_parse($date);

if ($parse_date['error_count'] > 0) {
    $date = null;
}
```

However, there's also a DB side solution where you can change the column to not accept 0000-00-00 as a date. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date