# How do I store NULL date in Mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I am trying to store the date as NULL when user not entering any value from datepicker

DatePicker HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label >Date of Birth</label>
    <!-- <input type="date" class="form-control" id="ac_date_of_birth" name="ac_date_of_birth" placeholder="Enter Date"> -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="ac_date_of_birth" name="ac_date_of_birth" tabindex="2" placeholder="Enter Date">
</div>
```

datepicker JS

```
$('#ac_date_of_birth').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
              format:'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

At Front end my date Format is dd/mm/yyyy like 25/04/2019
and I converted it to YY/mm/dd to store in Mysql Database

Here is my Codeigniter Code

```
$userInfo   =   $this->input->post();

$ac_date_of_birth = strtotime($userInfo['ac_date_of_birth']);
if (empty($userInfo['ac_date_of_birth'])) {      
  $ac_date_of_birth=NULL;

} else {
   $ac_date_of_birth = str_replace('/', '-', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($userInfo['ac_date_of_birth'])));

}
```

I want to store NULL in case user not select date or when the select selected date will be store
currently, it stores 1970/01/01

Comment: [Set html datepicker to null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27831248/2943403)

Comment: Why are you trying to save with `YY/mm/dd`?  Your table column is a DATE type column right?  Does the table / environment permit a null date value?  A date should be stored as `Y-m-d`.  Can you set a default value of `null` for that column and if the user doesn't provide a date, just omit that value/column from your query.

Comment: Actually @mickmackusa I think OP is converting correctly to `date('Y-m-d'` but lord alone knows why that is dont as part of a str_replace to remove `/` that are not there :)#

Comment: What are you replacing with this: `str_replace('/', '-', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($userInfo['ac_date_of_birth'])))`?

Comment: some date picker returns with / format and some with a - hyphen and MySQL required hyphen - format that's why I use this @mickmackusa

Comment: But you are dictating `date('Y-m-d')`.  Your str_replace() call can be safely omitted.  If you need to replace, replace at `$userInfo['ac_date_of_birth']`.

Comment: I found this solution   if (!empty($userInfo['ac_date_of_birth']))
      {      
        $data['user_date_of_birth'] = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('-', $userInfo['ac_date_of_birth'] )));
      }